# Shared Photos albums not visible on new iPad

Tags: ipad, icloud, photos

I bought an iPad and connected it to the same iCloud account as my laptop.  The photographs in the `Library` have been synchronized, but most of the `Shared Albums` have not been.  The sole shared album does not have any photographs in it.

Is there a setting that I need to toggle to allow this to occur?

Comment: On the iPad, have you checked whether in Settings > Photos, 'iCloud Photos' and 'Shared Albums' switches are both turned to "on" position? Also check Settings > Your_name > iCloud > Photos > Shared albums (If off, turn it on. If on, toggle it off and then on again)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to toggle the `Settings > Photos > Shared Albums` switch off then on.

Once I did this, the shared albums started to synchronize.